# CFWheels: Model FindAll() appends letter "s" in related table name

Tags: cfwheels

```
checklist = model("user_checklist").findAll(include="tb_machine_checklist");
```

Above is the query I am using to fetch records from a table called user_checklist and it is related to table called tb_machine_checklist.

Now there is a table called "tb_machine_checklist", however it it gives me an error saying;

```
The "tb_machine_checklists" table could not be found in the database.
```

Why is the "s" being added when I didn't specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to read the chapter in the documentation about [Conventions](http://docs.cfwheels.org/docs/conventions).

> CFWheels adopts a Rails-style naming conventions for database tables and model files. Think of a database table as a collection of model objects; therefore, it is named with a plural name. Think of a model object as a representation of a single record from the database table; therefore, it is named with a singular word.

Fortunately, CFWheels lets you override most conventions with a little bit of extra code.

In your `tb_machine_checklist` model's `init` method, add this line of code:

```
<cffunction name="init">
  <cfset table("tb_machine_checklist")>
</cffunction>
```

Then any queries that CFWheels writes for you will use your singular table name instead of the conventional plural one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the include in findAll specifies the model name, not the table Name. Wheels ORM pluralizes in some occasions the model Name and maps it to the table Name. Maybe you could explicitely set the table name for the model in the model?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this matter, My models were not named the same as my database tables. and once that was done properly, this problem went away.